# jsonify an array of strings

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array in my database that is being stored in the following format

> ["size:medium","height:10cm"]

this is problematic to display in a table.

Is there any way that I can convert this into a Javascript object or a JSON string like this?

> {"size":"medium","height":"10cm"
>   }

p.s:i know json.stringfy,json_encode.the thing is they have stored key value pair as one string

Comment: have you tried JSON.parse or json_encode? Please mention your effort as well to help us.

Comment: `{["size":"medium","height":"10cm"]}` this is not a valid Javascript object or JSON string.

Comment: the thing is someone as stored it already in ["size:medium","height:10cm"]
format means both key and value as on string

Comment: i want convert into json

Comment: and if you guys dont understand it doesnt mean you have to give negative

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**Note:** *Following code will make array of objects. I don't think `{["size:medium", "height:10cm"]}` is a valid object*

```js
(function() {
  var styleArr = ["size:medium", "height:10cm", "font-size: 18px"];
  var resultObject = {};

  styleArr.forEach(function(item) {
    var values = item.replace(/\"/g, '').split(':');
    resultObject[values[0]] = values[1];
  });

  console.log(resultObject)
})()
```

Comment: Nice but it creates a new object for each property.

Comment: @ShanShan Yes. I had updated and mentioned in it that it will create a Array of Objects. `{["size":"medium","height":"10cm"]}` is not a valid object since there is no key.

Comment: so for multiple style values, you want `{"size":"medium", "height":"10cm" }` or `[{"size":"medium"},{"height":"10cm"}]`

Comment: {"size":"medium", "height":"10cm" }

Comment: can u do this in php?

Answer (score 1):

You can build an object with the elements of the array and the left part as key and the right part as value of the by `:` separated strings.

```
array                       object
--------------------------- ---------------------------
[                      ->   {
    "size:medium",     ->       size: "medium",
    "height:10cm"      ->       height: "10cm"
]                      ->   }
```

```js
var array = ["size:medium", "height:10cm"],
    object = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var t = a.split(':');
        r[t[0]] = t[1];
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: ty you for you answer it there anyway to do this in php

Comment: Yes, but you should ask a separate question for each language rather than tag your single question with multiple languages. Otherwise someone looking for an answer in PHP may come here and only find Javascript answers, or vice-versa. In all cases you should show your effort along with the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use JSON.parse(), in order to convert your array in Javascript Object.

Answer (score -1):

**In PHP Use : json_encode(text)**

**In JavaScript : JSON.parse(text)**